# Azure table exception

Tags: java, android, azure, exception

Trying to get some info from table which is on Azure, but I get an exception, which I can't fix for more then two days. Please help.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.gaya.searchpeople-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.gaya.searchpeople-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.gaya.searchpeople-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.gaya.searchpeople-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.gaya.searchpeople-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.gaya.searchpeople-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.gaya.searchpeople-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.gaya.searchpeople-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.gaya.searchpeople-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.gaya.searchpeople-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.gaya.searchpeople-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.gaya.searchpeople-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.gaya.searchpeople-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableDeserializer.<clinit>(TableDeserializer.java:45) 
   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableDeserializer.parseSingleOpResponse(TableDeserializer.java:199) 
   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.QueryTableOperation.parseResponse(QueryTableOperation.java:143) 
   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.QueryTableOperation$1.postProcessResponse(QueryTableOperation.java:234) 
   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.QueryTableOperation$1.postProcessResponse(QueryTableOperation.java:191) 
   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:146) 
   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.QueryTableOperation.performRetrieve(QueryTableOperation.java:176) 
   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableOperation.execute(TableOperation.java:696) 
   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTable.execute(CloudTable.java:526) 
   at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTable.execute(CloudTable.java:493) 
   at com.example.gaya.searchpeople.LoginActivity$NetworkConnector.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:92) 
   at com.example.gaya.searchpeople.LoginActivity$NetworkConnector.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:71) 
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                    ... 19 more
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Comment: This doesn't look like an Azure Tables issue to me. It looks like your app cannot find your JsonFactory class (com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory) to use to deserialize Azure Table data. Which means that the package containing your deserializer isn't in your APK.

Comment: @RobReagan thanks, I didn't added a lib, you've helped me)

Comment: No worries. I'm glad it's working!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your issue was resolved, and according to the exception information `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory`, a missing library caused this issue.

Just as an additional content for the similar issue, sometimes external jars and android dependencies may be not packaged into apk, android offical website explains this case at [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/android-facet-page.html#d641364e265), as below.

[image]

Hope it helps for others.